# RxJS v5 Pausable Observable Interval

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5

With the `pausable` operator not implemented in RxJS v5, is there a better way to create a pausable interval? The code below works, but does so by keeping track of the last emitted value as an offset. It seems like there should be a better way...

```
const source = Rx.Observable.interval(100).share()
const offset = new Rx.BehaviorSubject(0)
let subscription;
let currentValue;

function start() {    
    subscription = source
        .subscribe(i => {
            currentValue = i + offset.value
      })
}



function pause() {
    source.take(1).subscribe(i => offset.next(i + offset.value))
    subscription.unsubscribe()
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/1542

Comment: @cartant That's helpful, but the source interval is still reset when it's paused, so keeping track of an offset value is still necessary as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 1):

The `share()` operator is [an alias for `.publish().refCount()`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-share). The `refCount()` means that the observable will clean itself up when no other subscribers to it exist. Because you're unsubscribing from source, it will clean itself up, then restart when `subscribe`d to again. Use `publish()` with `connect()` instead. Here's the code:

```
const source = Observable.interval(100).publish();
source.connect();

// Start with false, change to true after 200ms, then false again
// after another 200ms
const pauser = Observable.timer(200)
  .mapTo(true)
  .concat(Observable.timer(200).mapTo(false))
  .startWith(false);

const pausable = pauser
  .switchMap(paused => (paused ? Observable.never() : source))
  .take(10);

pausable.subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

See this jsbin for a running example: http://jsbin.com/jomusiy/3/edit?js,console.

Answer (score 0):

There's no general purpose way to do this. It depends on what exactly you mean by pausing and also what you're pausing. (Do you want to just stop emitting and then start again, do you buffer and drain, or do you effectively need to add a delay to the upstream, but otherwise preserve the distribution of upstream values in time?)

I have a way to do this in an efficient manner when the upstream is specifically a timer, as it is in your example. It is the answer to my own question here.

[RxJS (5.0rc4): Pause and resume an interval timer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40838308/rxjs-5-0rc4-pause-and-resume-an-interval-timer)

This one has the great advantage of preserving the source's value distribution in time, but just adding a delay to it.

For more general cases:

1. For cold observables: `switch` between a `never` and upstream. On pause, unsubscribe from upstream. `skip` ones that you've seen, and then `switch` to the `skip`ed stream. While unpaused you must maintain a count of how many values you've emitted, so that you can `skip` that many the next time someone unpauses. You only have to remember how many you've seen before. However, every unpause causes the cold observable to replay from the beginning. This could be *very* inefficient in the general case. The code would look something like this. `pauser` here would be a Subject that you can set to true or false to pause upstream.

   ```
   function pausableCold(pauser, upstream) {
       var seen = 0;
       return pauser.switch(paused => {
           if (paused) {
               return Observable.never();
           }
           else {
               return upstream.skip(seen).do(() => seen++);
           }
       });
   }
   ```
2. For hot or cold observables, you can use buffering. `buffer` while paused and then drain and concat to the hot upstream when unpaused. (This preserves all the values but but it doesn't preserve their distribution in time. Also, you should hot upstream with `publish` if it could be cold.)
3. The most efficient way is not really part of the Rx. What you *really* want is to tell the source to stop emitting and then start again. The way you do that is very specific to what the source is and how the source is generating values.